# Authentication issue with mail server

Tags: ubuntu, email-server, postfix, courier-imap

I followed the instructions at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostfixCompleteVirtualMailSystemHowto to setup a smtp and imap server on my local network.

But when i try to login with thunderbird (after creating mailbox with postfixadmin)
I get a "Password or user name wrong error.

this is the tail of /var/log/mail.err

```
Jan 26 04:18:15 NightHwack imapd: Connection, ip=[::ffff:192.168.1.4]
Jan 26 04:18:15 NightHwack authdaemond: received auth request, service=imap, authtype=login
Jan 26 04:18:15 NightHwack authdaemond: authmysql: trying this module
Jan 26 04:18:15 NightHwack authdaemond: authmysqllib: connected. Versions: header 50517, client 50529, server 50529
Jan 26 04:18:15 NightHwack authdaemond: SQL query: SELECT username, password, "", '5000', '5000', '/var/mail', "", "", name, "" FROM mailbox WHERE username = 'webmaster@xincoz.com' 
Jan 26 04:18:15 NightHwack authdaemond: password matches successfully
Jan 26 04:18:15 NightHwack authdaemond: authmysql: sysusername=<null>, sysuserid=5000, sysgroupid=5000, homedir=/var/mail, address=webmaster@xincoz.com, fullname=Webmaster, maildir=<null>, quota=<null>, options=<null>
Jan 26 04:18:15 NightHwack authdaemond: authmysql: clearpasswd=<null>, passwd=$1$e7d3bbc2$zWm3PmkfdCHAbz.kyRPld/
Jan 26 04:18:15 NightHwack authdaemond: Authenticated: sysusername=<null>, sysuserid=5000, sysgroupid=5000, homedir=/var/mail, address=webmaster@xincoz.com, fullname=Webmaster, maildir=<null>, quota=<null>, options=<null>
Jan 26 04:18:15 NightHwack authdaemond: Authenticated: clearpasswd=webmaster007, passwd=$1$e7d3bbc2$zWm3PmkfdCHAbz.kyRPld/
Jan 26 04:18:15 NightHwack imapd: chdir Maildir: No such file or directory
Jan 26 04:18:15 NightHwack imapd: webmaster@xincoz.com: No such file or directory
```

Folders in /var/mail/

```
webmaster 
root 
agent
```

please help me resolve this. 
Thank you :)

Comment: Your postfix is complaining about your Maildir being non existent.  Can you post your `postconf -n`?

Comment: her eis my **postconf -n** output
  http://pastebin.com/JpdNQC8r

Answer (score 0):

You missed the postfix configuration for use with virtual domains and users.

```
# Virtual Mailbox Domain Settings

virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_domains_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_limit = 51200000
virtual_minimum_uid = 5000
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
virtual_transport = virtual
```

There are other configurations you must check, as user creation and directory permissions.  These configurations are in the section 12 of the tutorial you are following.

Comment: The lines mentioned above seen to be present in the ,main.cf

Comment: Also I notice that the mailboxes is being created in /var/mail than in /home/vmail : although both postfix and courier config says /home/vmail is the folder

Comment: I didn't saw the lines in your `postconf` output.  Can you post your main.cf then?

Comment: sure here is the main.cf file http://pastebin.com/LA3mkewX

Comment: Found a syntax error on your `main.cf`.  Line 27 there is a `parameters` loose there, remove it and you may be good to go.

By the way, the command to check for syntax is `postfix check`.

Comment: Sorry, that seems to have been an error i made during copy pasting the file from vim. The actual file do not contain this. Sorry for the mixup